# Transfer Office license without account

Tags: microsoft-office, license, transfer

I'm trying to transfer an Office 2013 License from a computer that's not going to be used anymore to a new computer. After some googling I've only found forums that say I need to do something on my Microsoft account. Point is, I don't know the Microsoft account because I'm not the one who installed it, and I don't know who installed it so I can't ask for the account. I also can't check which account it is linked to because in Office it also asks me to login. The question is, is there any way to transfer the license without the account (like a file with a key or something)? Or is there anything else I can do to save this license?

Thanks in advance for your time/answers

Comment: See answer by Rohn007....https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_windows8/office-2013-license-transfer-from-old-to-new/8078ea83-6db2-4345-8283-aecfdc2c2f08

Comment: If you owned the license you'd have means of retrieving it. Because you do not own the license, you should not be trying to do what you say you're doing.

Comment: @music2myear I'm doing this for a foundation that specifically asked me to do this. The person who set up this laptop 6 years ago isn't part of the foundation anymore. So it's completely legal, but a bit complicated

Comment: Then the foundation owns the licenses and has means of proving this. However, the TYPE of license is key. Some software is licensed by seat, or locked to the computer it is installed on. You, on behalf of the organization, should speak with the people the license was purchased from if you don't know the type of license and what it allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Office 2013 a volume license or a one-time purchase? Since the important thing you should consider is how to activate Office 2013 on the new computer, I will explain the three activation methods of Office 2013 to you:

1. If the Office 2013 is a volume licensed version and was activated by [KMS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ff793434(v=technet.10)), you should re-activate Office 2013 on the new computer. Note that to qualify for KMS activation, a network must meet the activation threshold: KMS hosts activate client computers only after meeting this threshold. Therefore, KMS is suitable for multiple computers in an organization to request activation at the same time. You can review [KMS activation of Office 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2013-resource-kit/ee624357(v=office.15)).
2. If the Office 2013 is a volume licensed version and was activated by MAK. Since you can successfully activate Office 2013 using MAK only when the number of activations is sufficient, I suggest you can find the number of activations remaining on a MAK by going to the "Volume Licensing Service Center" (VLSC) or by using the Volume Activation Management Tool (VAMT). How to activate it please refer to [Activate Office 2013 MAK client](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2013-resource-kit/dn385359(v=office.15)). For MAK, installing on a new computer means that you need to use the number of activation licenses once. If the number of times is exhausted, you need to purchase again.

3.If Office 2013 is a one-time purchase and come with a product key. First thing we need to know is exactly what type of Office license you bought. Is it 1-computer Office 2013 or 5-computer Office 365 (2013)?

If it is 1-computer license, you have to distinguish between a "retail" license and a "Product Key Card" / "PKC" license. The Retail license had a list price of US$139, while the Product Key Card was US$10-20 less than that. If you have a Retail license, you have the right to transfer it to the new computer. If you have the PKC, then you are out of luck. Part of the reason it is cheaper is that it is disposable. It is permanently tied to the first computer it is installed on. When that computer is sold or dies, the Office PKC license goes with it.
For more details, please refer to [Office 2013 License transfer from old to new computer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_windows8/office-2013-license-transfer-from-old-to-new/8078ea83-6db2-4345-8283-aecfdc2c2f08?auth=1)

Comment: This is a good and helpful answer. The problem is that licensing questions are nearly always legal questions, and Superuser cannot offer legal opinions. This is probably the best/most information OP can get from us about the issue. And it really is going to come down to their talking to the seller of their license or Microsoft.

Comment: "refer to this link" - What link?

Comment: I have re-edited my reply. The link is  [Office 2013 License transfer from old to new computer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_windows8/office-2013-license-transfer-from-old-to-new/8078ea83-6db2-4345-8283-aecfdc2c2f08?auth=1).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Office 2013 was activated with a licence key then you could download and run "Advanced Tokens Manager" (by Josh Cell software) on your old computer. This will allow you to save a file containing your Office license details which, along with the software, needs to be copied to your new computer.

On your new computer, you can install Office 2013, run Advanced Tokens Manager again and then restore your license. In the spirit of fairness, once you've done the transfer then you should uninstall Office from your old computer.

This process isn't officially supported by Microsoft, so use at your own risk.